# Ads for G&FH on other SE sites

Tags: discussion, publicity

As we're not a graduated site, we can't have [community promotion ads](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/248214/how-do-we-get-community-promotion-ads-on-beta-sites) on our site at this point. What we can do is create adverts for G&FH that show up in the sidebar on other related sites in the SE network.

Let's create some ads here, and submit them to the Community Promotion Ad posts on the relevant graduated site. Ads typically need 6 upvotes before they are displayed on a site. Ads need to be 300x250 px, PNG or non-animated GIF, no more than 150 KB, and 1 px border if white background. Ads are reset annually, but there's no reason one can't be added mid-way through the year.

I think it helps to tailor the ads to the site they will appear on, rather than a generic ad. I've started one example for Biology SE to get the process going. Feel free to include designs or ideas for other sites we could advertise on. If you have an idea but no inclination to make an ad, myself or someone else may be able to make the ad. What other SE sites might it be useful to have an ad on?

Comment: The [history.se]  SE would be a good option, if it were not [still in Beta](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/5169/history) like us, and therefore not able to host community ads.

Comment: I note History SE is no longer in Beta, so  might be an option.

Answer (score 4):

> Unfortunately, no Community Adds at Photography SE Meta reached 6 in
> their [2020 voting](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7027/community-promotion-ads-2020) and so they are not part of the Community Ads initiative
> in 2021 - see
> [The future of Community Promotion, Open Source, and Hot Network Questions Ads](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/364556/the-future-of-community-promotion-open-source-and-hot-network-questions-ads).

---

For [Photography SE](https://photo.stackexchange.com/), and its 40,000 registered users.

[image]

Support this ad by upvoting at: https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5465/63680
(required target is 6 upvotes)

---

I posted a Meta Photography SE question which seemed to entice some of their members to add the extra two votes we needed to see our ad start to appear there: https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5506/is-photography-se-interested-in-family-history

---

We can see from https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/5360 that our community ad is attracting the most clicks per day of the 2 community ads that they display.

Answer (score 2):

For [Biology SE](https://biology.stackexchange.com/), and its 22,000 registered users:

[image]

Support this ad by upvoting at: https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3689/18860
The required target for it to start being displayed is 6 upvotes and we are currently at 5 - so we need just one more!

Comment: Great ad! It has a vote there now:-)

Comment: I just gave another little nudge at https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3521/community-promotion-ads-2017/3689#comment4957_3528 - hope it pays off and does not have the opposite effect

Comment: I am not a fan of this one as it may attract more ethnicity questions which we've said are off topic.

Comment: @CRSouser We have a lot of DNA questions which are heavily biology-related. Also, I wasn't aware all ethnicity questions were off-topic (we have several quality questions about DNA and ethnicity, and we even have an [tag:ethnicity] tag)

Comment: @HarryVervet The ones like Am I Black/White/Native American/etc ? Questions on understanding DNA ethnicity differences and such are in scope but we don't do medical / health questions and we don't do purely ethnic questions typically unless they have more depth to them.. I'm mostly against  the wording of the ad and use of the word "Biology". We are Genealogy/Family History.

Comment: @CRSouser The only reason the word Biology was used was because the ad was for a Biology site. It's best to tailor ads to their specific audience. If you can think of something better to write, I am open to it being changed. How about "Who's in your DNA?"

Comment: @HarryVervet 'Got genes? Try Genealogy'

Comment: As someone who was heavily into zoology for a decade, I think any of the many zoologists at [biology.se] will have instant connection with "What's **your** biology?" because even though we are just one of the millions of species that interests them, we are the one that they know best.

Comment: @HarryV. - I think it would be great if you could re-post your ad at https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4212/community-ads-for-2021 - I tried to do that quickly just now but seemed to have a rep issue there that I didn't have time to look into,

Answer (score 2):

I don't have any artwork but a catchphrase for a G&FH SE ad on the [GIS Stack Exchange](http://gis.stackexchange.com), which has about 68,000 registered users, could be:

> *Where's* your ancestry?

Over the past 10 or so years the GIS industry has made a concerted effort to "own" the word "where" and so it would help associate the subject matter of the two sites.

With Family HiStory Mapping being a focus of mine I would love to see more GIS Professionals taking an interest in Genealogy & Family History.

Perhaps a graphic could be a globe of the world centred on the Atlantic Ocean (so the Americas, Europe and Africa are all visible), with a few bright yellow stars at locations like New York, the Carribbean, West Africa and London, and a 19th century ship placed in the centre of the ocean, and maybe a double helix to represent DNA placed somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

I think we might be able to make a connection with some of the 157,000 users registered for [English Language and Usage Stack Exchange](https://english.stackexchange.com/) around the opportunity for them to see interesting examples of palaeography and phraseology from hitherto unseen or unsurfaced documents.

Perhaps a catchphrase and graphic could be something like this in a large Old English font:

> English your ancestors spake

My old English grammar is not researched but hopefully you get the idea.

The same idea could be applied with lesser effect to the other graduated language site:

- [Japanese Language](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/) (13K registered users)

It is a shame that language sites like [German](https://german.stackexchange.com/) (17K users), [French](https://french.stackexchange.com/) (11K users), ..., [Latin](https://latin.stackexchange.com/) (1.6K users), etc have not yet graduated and therefore are not eligible to host community ads.

Comment: I like this idea....

Comment: @HarryVervet me too - not sure why it garnered a downvote - its the biggest site that our ad would be relevant on, and I think it may be the one that our ad would be the most relevant on.

Comment: The link between English Language and G&FH is admittedly a little tenuous...but I'll make an ad we can try on that site anyway (unless anyone else would like to try??) As I see it, it can't hurt to have additional ads however tenuous the link is.

Comment: As most of us can't reace our ancestry back to Old (or even Middle) English, can I suggest a more recent version -- like 18th century secretary hand, although finding a font might be difficult so you may have to superimpose the 'slogan' on a sample instead. And I strongly suggest researching the words to use in the slogan as well, to make sure they're accurate.